# Why does adaptive voxel remesh cause self intersections?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, remesh

I don't know why but when I use adaptive voxel remesh in Blender it returns these kinds of self intersections. I know I can resolve them by relax mesh filter brush but it'll ruin my surface quality.

The settings are the following:

- Voxel Size : 0.0035 m
- Adaptivity :  0.008 m
- Fix poles
- Volume

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to the official docs, any Adaptivity>0 disables "Fix poles"., - I think it may be related to that (or something to do with n-gons). I notice that if the missing face in your image were filled, the adjacent "large rectangle" immediately to the left would be the only visible n-gon in the entire topology. Something is stopping blender from creating that n-gon, and I have the feeling it's Adaptivity related.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett what ? is that mean adaptive remesh is useless ?